# introduction materials to the actor model?

Tags: resource-request, textbook, concurrency

I am looking for some introductions to the actor model. I don't mind books in specific programming languages, as long as they don't distract away or restrict the presentation of the model

Is this a good one?

> Actors: A Model of Concurrent Computation in Distributed Systems (MIT Press), by Gul Agha, 1986

I am uncertain because

- it is a PhD dissertation which might be for things that were experimental and then found useless, and
- it was in 1986 and I am not sure how much the model has changed.

Thanks.

Comment: We will need to know who the target audience is. Yes you, so tell us a little about your self. What is you experience / level of education? What is your motivation for learning this?

Comment: kindergarten. interested.

Comment: "Everything I needed to know, I Iearned in kindergarten." - Robert Fulghum. If only that were true of all of us.

Comment: I don't see much when I search, except for references to my favorite missing in action person, Bret Victor. You could try this link as a starting point: [A World Without Agile, Can You Imagine?](https://hurlbert.medium.com/without-agile-where-would-you-go-11712c15403c). I am not sure of the need for concurrency in much mainstream development, but I suppose things could change. People could get sharper wits. ("The universe is full of magical things patiently waiting for our wits to grow sharper" - Eden Phillpotts)

Comment: @ScottRowe what are needed in mainstream development?

Comment: @Tim What I was thinking of is the large amount of basic data and forms programming, with just 'CRUD' data access (Create record, Read, Update, Delete). Object Oriented is not needed for that really, and concurrency certainly is not, beyond adding a timestamp to the Where clause. What is your interest in Actor? It was designed for systems where resources are being continually reused at high speed, like a telephone system. I created a multithreaded data server, but there was no contention, just separate requests, so not much need for concurrency. What would you like to find out?